# Material turns pink after any normal map is attached to it while the normal map works on other materials

Tags: texturing, materials

When I attach a normal map to a specific material, it turns pink while the normal map works on other textures. A bump node is currently being used for the normal map. The image source is not missing.

Nodes:
[image]

Running the texture through a normal map does not work either.
[image: normal map]

Comment: This is not the correct way to use a normal map.  A normal map needs to be run through a normal map node.  Generally speaking, you use a bump map *or* a normal map, not both.  A normal map is dependent on mesh and UV map, and they do not necessarily work right when used on a mesh/UV for which they were not designed.  If what you've been doing has worked elsewhere, that's just luck.

Comment: @Nathan Thanks a lot for replying but if I understood correctly (img --> normalmap --> principled BSDF) it still has the same output

Answer (score 0):

**Solution** after randomly playing around in the editor I have found out that switching to Cycles from Eevee fixed the problem. I still have no idea on why it only works on cycles but not in Eevee.